# dpkg nvidia package problem dependencies

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg

— fixad 
I was able to remove every drive from Nvidia, and then install version nvidia-340 where the dependency where. I think it works now. 
—

I can boot my computer and it seems works but can't upgrade and install packages. Problem is that I can't fix dependencies for nvidia (or is it depend for some program) I think. I have low knowledge about how dependencies work. I did install programs for a wile ago but with no problems. This is my flight sim X-plane. Ubuntu 18.04.4 64.

I have tried more things after the text below. Started boot USB, boot from advanced to and I was able to `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` and `sudo apt remove nvidia*` 
but if I install nvidia again the same problem even whit other version of Nvidia driver.

Tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install` same problem

```
----
conny@conny-flyg:~$ sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.original
[sudo] password for conny: 
conny@conny-flyg:~$ sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status.original
cp: target '/var/lib/dpkg/status.original' is not a directory
conny@conny-flyg:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libllvm8 libllvm8:i386 libnvidia-common-390 libnvidia-common-435 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 linux-headers-5.3.0-28 linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic
  linux-modules-5.3.0-28-generic linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-28-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-430 libnvidia-gl-430:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-430 libnvidia-gl-430:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/50,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 240 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 268750 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-430'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-430:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-430'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-430:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
conny@conny-flyg:~$ sudo dpkg -configure -a
dpkg: error: unknown option -o

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
conny@conny-flyg:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-430:
 nvidia-driver-430 depends on libnvidia-gl-430 (= 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2); however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-430:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-430 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64:
 libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64 depends on libnvidia-gl-430; however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-430:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386:
 libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 depends on libnvidia-gl-430; however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-430:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-driver-430
 libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64
 libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386
-----
Software Update
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libnvidia-ifr1-435: Depends: libnvidia-gl-435 but it is not installed
nvidia-driver-435: Depends: libnvidia-gl-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not installed
                   Depends: nvidia-dkms-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-compute-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-decode-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-encode-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-utils-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-435 (= 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
---
```

Sorry in advance, Handicap, hard to read and see. /Conny